# Как сделать границу рамки по центру между верхним и нижним элементом?

Tags: html, css

Например, чтобы записать такое: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создаю табличку. Вот её код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">-</td>
    <td>1</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 1px solid">2</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Но здесь я использую рамку над двойкой, поэтому это не то.

Как сделать на уровне его? Как на картинке.

P.S. Рамка вокруг не лишняя.

Comment: https://www.mathjax.org/#demo

Comment: https://jsbin.com/qitefox/edit?html,output , https://jsbin.com/gozipak/edit?html,css,output

Comment: А есть у кого вариант на моём примере? Без воды.